# jQuery animation blocks mobile scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Heelo.
I am using some jQuery and CSS in a template to animate some page elements. When i scroll down the page the elements fade in from the left and right. I have it set up so that the animation does not trigger on the mobile version. Everything works fine except i cannot scroll down the page past a certain point on my mobile device.

Here is a preview link: http://unbouncepages.com/voxel/

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Every time the window is scrolled...
    $(window).scroll( function(){
      // ***Feature Section***
      // Check the location of each desired element
        $('#lp-pom-box-254').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

          //If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({opacity:'1', left:'355px'},900);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

CSS:

```
#lp-pom-box-254 {
    opacity:0;
    left:0;
  }
```

I apologize for the vague explanation,
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should change this line:

```
   var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
```

to this:

```
   var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
```

.position().top doesn't seem to work everywhere. Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: UPDATE: Issue is fixed now, turns out my mobile chrome version was the culprit.